# How to add mutil-command line arguments to open chrome in android?

Tags: google-chrome, blink

I'm trying to run the chrome with command line argument via adb terminal in android. And it works through writing one flag to /data/local/chrome-command-line, e.g: 
`echo "chrome --single-process" > /data/local/chrome-command-line`.
Now I want to make chrome running with single-process mode and no sandbox, then I set the flags as follows:
`echo "chrome --single-process --no-sandbox --no-startup-window" > /data/local/chrome-command-line` 
or
`echo "chrome --single-process,--no-sandbox,--no-startup-window" > /data/local/chrome-command-line`.
But it doesn't work because the process of sandbox is still exists.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have tried to the way and it also does't work. `adb shell am start \
  -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
  -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity \
  --es activeUrl "http://chromium.org" \
  --esa commandLineArgs "--single-process,--no-sandbox"`. Becuase the am command doesn't support the esa option.